# How to model a wizard-like sequential process in REST?

Tags: api, rest, web

How to model a wizard-like sequential process in REST?

Each step is long and async, each step needs new client input based on results from previous step. Most of the samples I found only involves adding a new element to a collection and then modifying the element so I don't know how to apply to my case.

If I try to make an analogy to the process, it will be like this:

Client submit mystery package

Server slowly unpacks it

It's cake! Client input how many slices to cut

Server cut cake slowly

Client get sliced cake

It's bomb! Client input whether to cut green line or red line

Server disarm bomb slowly

Client get disarmed bomb

Unpacking, cutting, disarming are async sequential singular action with singular output, the samples apply to multiple elements in a collection so it feels weird when I try to model these singular actions...

Thanks.

Comment: The solution provided by @guillaume31 on following link might answer your question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309680/rest-api-design-for-web-pages-with-wizards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to model a wizard-like sequential process in REST?

The same way you would model a wizard-like sequential process with HTML forms.

> Each step is long and async, each step needs new client input based on results from previous step.

Doesn't change things very much.

In HTML, the user would follow a link/bookmark to a form.  The user would fill in the form, and hit the "Make Soup" button.  The contents of the form get sent to the server in an http request.  The server copies that information into the domain model, and sends a bunch of html back that says  "It's not soup yet; click here to check if it is soup."  User clicks the link to ask if it is soup.  The server sends back another html response denying that it is soup.  Eventually, the server answers one of these queries by admitting that it *is* soup, and here's the next form that you need.  And on and on you go, until the protocol is completed.

And so: you tell the server that you want it to open a mystery package.  The server redirects you to a progress report.  The representation of the progress report is a document that tells you to be patient, and includes a single link that tells you how to get an updated copy of the progress report.  If the mystery package has finally been opened, the representation of the progress report changes to include a link to the next step in the protocol.

> the samples apply to multiple elements in a collection so it feels weird when I try to model these singular actions...

[Jim Webber](http://www.scandevconf.se/db/REST%20-%20DDD%20in%20the%20Large.pptx.pdf)

> URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.  Work (ex: issuing commands to the domain model) is a side effect of managing resources.
>
> Resources adapt your domain model for the web